# Including monochrome TIFF

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, external-files, bitmap

I have a monochrome TIFF (hand-drawn ornament) which I want to include in my book, but I want in not black-and-white, but pantone-and-white — the book will be printed in two colors.

What should be my steps?

Comment: Other than the tag "tikz-pgf", what is the connection of this posting to TeX and friends?

Comment: @Paul Gaborit: Thanks for the link, I will try if the solution works not only with vector graphics, but also with bitmaps (as in my case).

Comment: @Mico: OK, I want to make a file for the press (not only for the screen), which will have correct color separation model, and I want to do it by the means of (XeLa)TeX — where else should I ask this question about right workflow?

Comment: @pantlmn If your key point is pantone color ("spot color") and good separation, it is a specific problem that  is not related with the coloroation of an external TIFF image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that come to my mind:

1. Open picture in InDesign, color with appropriate pantone, save as PDF and include. (I am kind of afraid of such a long chain tiff -> InD -> pdf -> pdf). Will the final result display the pantone correctly?
2. Redraw picture as a vector image in Inkscape, export to Tikz and include. (This will result in some loss, because the picture is not of such a good resolution to be easily vectorized.)

Comment: Finally I had to use the chain TIFF -> InDesign -> monochrome PDF with Pantone -> XeLaTeX -> final PDF. `Tikz` library `fadings` uses only RGB color space, and I needed CMYK + Pantone.